# NRF24 and usb digispark

Tags: nrf24l01+, digispark

I want to connect NRf24 module with digispark and use USB capabilities at same time.
currently, i use this conexion diagram:

```
               NC      PB5  1|o   |8  Vcc --- nRF24L01  VCC, pin2 --- LED --- 5V
nRF24L01  CE, pin3 --- PB3  2|    |7  PB2 --- nRF24L01  SCK, pin5
nRF24L01 CSN, pin4 --- PB4  3|    |6  PB1 --- nRF24L01 MOSI, pin6
nRF24L01 GND, pin1 --- GND  4|    |5  PB0 --- nRF24L01 MISO, pin7
```

Bu my problem is that as you see in this diagram CE and CSN are in the USB + and - pins:
[image]
I just want that my module receive data so, i think that if i power up every time CE pin and i change CSN pin to PB5 this may work but, in fact this don't
I can't use 3 pin connexion because i don't have capacitor and my project is for Wednesday
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: so, what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

it is possible to use digispark with NRF24 and USB keyboard without use system that need capacitors as the tree cable solution? I just want to use the digispark as RX

Answer (score 1):

As per https://digistump.com/wiki/digispark/tutorials/basics:

*Pin 3 and Pin 4 (P3 and P4) are used for USB communication and programming, while you can use them in your circuit if you are not using USB communication, you may have to unplug your circuit during programming if the circuit would impede the pin states or dramatically affect the voltage levels on these pins.*